# how to use npm run build on your react app?

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I recently created a small website with react app , but after running , `npm run build` in the browser i find static folder in the browser in debugger , with my whole react app , components and app.js even node_modules , and of course i think , there is something wrong with npm run build , because , this is not how it suppose to work , by the way i'm using nginx and pm2 to connect my back-end to the website , both on the same server to deploy my website , so the question here , is the error here in nginx configuration or on react build script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create React App, give you a webpack configuration that by default include the option to include the source on the build.

You need to do this:
1. Eject your create-react-app project by running `npm run eject`:
2. Open your `/config/webpack.config.prod.js`.
3. Remove the line who contains the `devtool: 'source-map'`.
4. Build, and deploy your app again.

With this, you should don't have the source on your browser, check this if you need more information of webpack config: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

**NOTE**: If you don't wanna eject your code, you can use [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire-webpack), and don't touch the base code of CRA and instead override with your configuration.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: after running `npm run eject` and removing devtool like you said the files wasn't there in static folder any more , but under static , there was a folder named media something , and there was all my info in it . i did exactly what you told me , the files wasn't in static folder , but another folder appeared with the name media and it has all my info in it

Comment: Weird, can you show us your webpack configuration? and what is the exact name of the folder that's created now?

Comment: I'm new to webpack , i didn't use it before it's first time , i changed devtool: 'none' and removed from build -> static -> css folder removed .map files , it worked for now, no problems , thanks a lot for the help , one more question if you may , i'm trying to use process.env in front end to protect url end point and important code , but i have no idea where to start , with webpack config , do you have any info , from where to start ?

Comment: To handle environment variables what you need to do is implement https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv, if you need it on FE, implement this instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack, with this, you will be able to use environment variables from anywhere of your building code.

Comment: @MiguelAngel how to change this line `const servedUrl =
    envPublicUrl || (publicUrl ? url.parse(publicUrl).pathname : './');` in config/path.js with out eject npm , and use rewire or react-app-rewired. can you give example ?